# Location of file is unchanged after changing List of folders via Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to change file location of existing file via Roslyn.

```
var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(Constants.pathToSolution).Result;

DocumentId documentIdToMove = ConsoleHelpers.GetDocumentIdForDocumentWithName(solution, "Person.cs");

var newSolution = solution.WithDocumentFolders(documentIdToMove, new List<string> { "SecondLevel", "ThirdLevel" });

msWorkspace.TryApplyChanges(newSolution);
```

Originally, the file is in the "SecondLevel" folder inside main project folder.
According to documentation, WithDocumentFolders method should create a new solution instance with the document specified updated to be contained in
the sequence of logical folders.

After running the code, program is completed without any exceptions, file is changed on disk, but the location remains the same. Also, TryApplyChanges method returns true.
When creating new document in a project and then saving changes to disk, the new file is created in location specified by the sequence of folders without any issues.

Is changing location of existing file in project and then saving the changes to disk possible?

Comment: Does `TryApplyChanges` return false?

Comment: @SLaks : No, it returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing folders like this isn't supported. Feel free to [file a bug on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).